# C++ - Is it possible to sort 2D string vector by single column?

Tags: c++, vector

I have two-dimensional vector

```
std::vector< std::vector< std::string > > stockVector;
```

Which looks like:

```
{  
   { 1, "Title 1", 1, 2.20 },  
   { 2, "Title 2", 2, 3.30 },  
   // ...  
}
```

Now I need to sort it by single column at same time - how can I do this?

Comment: No, it cannot "looks like" that. That's not a vector of `std::string`s.

Comment: [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a custom comparator.

Comment: maybe you need `std::tuple` not `std::vector` for inner type?

Comment: BTW, your second `vector`, looks like it represents some kind of object. It would be better represented in a `class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data looks actually like this:

```
std::vector< std::vector< std::string > > stockVector
{
   { "1", "Title 1", "1", "2.20" },
   { "3", "Title 3", "3", "4.30" },
   { "2", "Title 2", "2", "3.30" },
};
```

You can simply use the `std::sort` with a custom coparator:

```
const int columnId = 0;
std::sort(stockVector.begin(), stockVector.end(), [&columnId](const std::vector<std::string> &item1, const std::vector<std::string> &item2)
{
    return item1[columnId] < item2[columnId];
});
```

Which sorts the collection according to the first column.

Comment: Works great! Is it possible to set column like parameter in function?

Comment: Sure, you can capture a variable in the lambda expression. I've updated the example.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for myself?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) (if no duplicates allowed) or a [`std::multiset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) then you can pass the comparator as a constructor argument. If you do it this way you will be guaranteed that the container is always sorted. The down-side is increased cost of insertion and deletion.

```
using StringVec = std::vector<std::string>;
auto compare = [](const StringVec& item1, const StringVec& item2){ 
     return item1[0] < item2[0]; 
};
std::set< StringVec, decltype(compare)> stockVector(compare);
```

Comment: This is true, however it is likely the OP wants to be able to sort the container on any chosen column on the fly